# Creating a new project in Android studio-Kotlin error

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am very new to Kotlin and I am creating a new project that supports Kotlin in Android Studio 3.0 canary.

This project is having two issues.

1. The R file is not getting resolved
2. The package name must be a '.' separated identifier list

What should I do now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do `clean project` and then `build` then post what error you are getting.

Comment: @Nisargi Joshi If R.is not resolvedYou compile Your Project One Time R. is resolved

Comment: Yes, I have cleaned the project and build it, the same error occurs.

Comment: @AshishShahi, compiling again doesn't resolve my issue.

Comment: @NisargiJoshi can You work on Android Previous Version

Comment: @AshishShahi Yes I am 2.5 experience android developer and after trying all the possible solutions I have posted this question here. I hope I can work very well.

Answer (score 23):

I assume you are using one of [Kotlin keywords](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html) in your package name.

To fix compilation error just surround the Keywords like `in` ,`as`,`is` with Grave accent ( ` ). E.g.
**`is`.package.name**,
**`in`.company.app**

Hope, it'll help you.

Answer (score 4):

This happens when you use a domain name with ".in" or any 2 character TLD in domain name while creating the project. This should be resolved if you create with a 3 character TLD domain name. Otherwise you can use as in_.xyz

Comment: This is the case that it happens for me when i have a package starting with 'in' but can't agree with the solution.

Comment: Agreed. It's not a solution but a workaround instead. Because there shouldn't be a restriction for creating projects with 2 character TLD domain names.